# How to change my regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have an regular Expression:

```
string DefaultInternalUseridPattern = "^(?i)((CEU)|(APA)|(NAM))\\\\(((ADM.){0,1}([a-z]{8}))|((SVC.){0,1}((CEU.)|(APA.)|(NAM.)|(HEI.))[a-z]*))$";
```

I want to replace the last part:
(CEU.)|(APA.)|(NAM.)|(HEI.)

With something that matches to 3 Letter and then a `.`

I tried some stuff but didn't get the solution for my problem.

Comment: A literal `.` is meant, right? Then it must be escaped. Try [`@"^(?i)(CEU|APA|NAM)\\((ADM\.)?([a-z]{8})|(SVC\.)?([A-Z]{3}\.)[a-z]*)$"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3fi)(CEU%7cAPA%7cNAM)%5c%5c((ADM%5c.)%3f(%5ba-z%5d%7b8%7d)%7c(SVC%5c.)%3f(%5bA-Z%5d%7b3%7d%5c.)%5ba-z%5d*)%24&i=Text). Use a verbatim string literal. Note that if you need to only match uppercase letters there, you'd need to use them in a `(?-i:[A-Z]{3}\.)` group.

Comment: could you please provide some text for testing?

Answer (score 3):

Your expression is overloaded with capturing groups, I doubt you are using them and suggest removing those redundant ones. That will simplify any further manipulations with it.

Note that literal dots in the pattern must be escaped.

I also see you are using a regular string literal while a verbatim string literal is much more comfortable to define regex patterns with in C#.

Try

```
@"^(?i)(CEU|APA|NAM)\\((ADM\.)?([a-z]{8})|(SVC\.)?([A-Z]{3}\.)[a-z]*)$"
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3Fi)(CEU%7CAPA%7CNAM)%5C%5C((ADM%5C.)%3F(%5Ba-z%5D%7B8%7D)%7C(SVC%5C.)%3F(%5BA-Z%5D%7B3%7D%5C.)%5Ba-z%5D%2A)%24&i=Text), I changed the 4 alternative group into `[A-Z]{3}\.`.

Note that if you need to only match uppercase letters there, you'd need to use them in a `(?-i:[A-Z]{3}\.)` group.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of all the un-needed capture groups and use this

Raw: `^(?i)(?:CEU|APA|NAM)\\(?:(?:ADM\.)?[a-z]{8}|(?:SVC\.)?[A-Z]{3}\.[a-z]*)$`
Verbatim: `@"^(?i)(?:CEU|APA|NAM)\\(?:(?:ADM\.)?[a-z]{8}|(?:SVC\.)?[A-Z]{3}\.[a-z]*)$"`

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 (?i)                      # Be careful here, this says case insensitive
                           # for all subsequent letter matching.
 (?: CEU | APA | NAM )
 \\ 
 (?:
      (?: ADM \. )?
      [a-z]{8} 
   |  
      (?: SVC \. )?
      [A-Z]{3} \.
      [a-z]* 
 )
 $
```

Comment: There is nothing bad in using capturing groups in a .NET regex. The `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` flag will make sure no stack is created for unnamed, numbered, capturing groups. See MSDN reference: [*This allows unnamed parentheses to act as noncapturing groups without the syntactic clumsiness of the expression `(?:…)`.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Your always talking to me buddy, but I have no idea what you're saying. Dot-Net Group counting or order has a default setting if that's what you mean. As to the _stack_, unless you're the author of that engine, you should find out from them.